# PHP validate form before sending to the "action"

Tags: php, forms, validation

I've ended up in a situation I've not been in before. A client has forms provided by a third party company who take care of various newsletters and other admin tasks when forms are submitted, but amazingly they have NO validation. The form action goes straight to another server and not to the server I'm working on. Therefore I don't see how I can add some validation myself..

Ideally, I need to vet the form for spam and validate a captcha code, and then send to the original form action. I've added some front-end validation with jS, but this is of course only for enhancing the UI and not for serious validation.

Does anyone know if I can do anything with PHP..? Many thanks.

Comment: in front end u cant do anything with php.u cant run php until it reaches server.in frontend check onsubmit of form before submitting.

Comment: final validation must be done at the "action" script linked by the form. Think about it: if it was possible otherwise, Man in the Middle attacks would be extremely common.

Comment: Definitely  you can do a lot with PHP. You can validate input on your server and then send it to other servers with `curl` for example.

Comment: Yes, I already know the theory of the form action. Effectively I need to post to myself and THEN to the action if the data validates ok.

Comment: This is probably not a good idea, but it certainly *is* possible with PHP (by making use of libraries such as `cURL` to **re**-post the form inputs to the client server).

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be a good idea given the actual situation.  The absence of validation in the 3rd party script is a bad idea though...

Answer (score 1):

You could basically submit the form to a PHP page of yours, validate there, and if correct send back the request server-side to the original target (3rd party site). Strange though that a provider doesn't offer any kind of validation...

Comment: The lack of validation is mind-boggling. I just found out that the form data also gets inserted straight into their database too! 

I don't know how I'd sent the data to the third party with PHP. If I have my $_POST variable contents validated, how would I send this across when I'm done with the data?

Comment: See comments, you could use curl to generate an HTTP request from your server-side code when entries are valid. Basically all you would have to do besides validation is add all the posted values to a new request, send it, and test for result. Tis is very "old-school" though , 3rd parties typically offer some kind of API to communicate with their backend. I also found [this](http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php) that could be of help if not using curl, but I'm not into PHP myself so I couldn't tell if that's good to use this or not...

Comment: Given the fact that they offer no validation, I won't hope for an API. I'll look into cURL and your link and see if I can find a workable solution. Thanks for the input.